# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error, memory management issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I've read that this error comes from memory-management issues such as sending a message to an object which has been released. I am getting the error right after the comment "output information about songs in the 'info' array", in the first line of that second 'for' section. Is the info array not storing the objects that I am giving it in the first 'for' section?

Any other ideas?

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init]; //query iPod library
NSMutableArray *info; //create array to hold songs that fit
NSArray *allSongs = [query collections];

//only add those songs which have not
//been played since last login

for (MPMediaItem *recent in allSongs) {
    NSDate *lastPlayed = [recent valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate];
    BOOL uploadInfo = [[PlayedSinceLastLogin alloc] initWithLastPlayedDateOfSong:lastPlayed] ;
    if (uploadInfo == YES) {
        [info addObject:recent];
    }
}

//output information about songs
//in the 'info' array

for (MPMediaItem *played in info) {
    NSString *playCount = [played valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount];
    NSString *lastPlayed = [played valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate];
    NSString *songTitle =
    [played valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *artistName =
    [played valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    NSString *albumName =
    [played valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    NSLog (@"\n %@ by %@, from album %@, played since last login.\nLast Played:%@.\nTotal Play Count: %@.", songTitle, artistName, albumName, lastPlayed,playCount);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've ever actually created an instance of `NSMutableArray` for `info` to point to, so the bad access error is probably due to attempting to treat some random bit of memory as an initialized object.

Change

```
NSMutableArray *info;
```

to

```
NSMutableArray *info = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: As a side note, if you're really paranoid, it's a good idea to nil-init if you're not ready to assign a value:

NSMutableArray *info = nil;

Comment: Very nice! I think it was previously an ivar before the method went from a - to a +. Thanks so much!

Comment: do I also have to cread instances of UITextView objects? I am getting a similar error when I try to change textView.Text to the string I just made.

Comment: Yes, all objects have to be created somewhere; you can't ever just declare and use them. Many times your UITextView objects will be created by the runtime when you load a nib file, but if they aren't you will have to do it manually.